# Loading large web page in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Whenever I load a large web page in a UIWebView in my app, it always crashes (low memory) after a few seconds before the page is fully loaded. The page is about 500k in size. the page loads fine in safari, however i noticed that the entire page is not rendered initially. (showing a checkerboard background)

How can I do that so that UIWebView doesn't crash when loading a big file?

Answer (score 0):

Well One simple approach that works in Optimizing UIWebView is pretty simple and I found it effective in one of my app.
Creating new instances of UIWebView each time on user's action is not a feasible solution and most likely crashes the app after a few loads. 
Keep a Single Instance of UIWebView that you can work with throughout your app, so that you don't have to call ALLOC on UIWebView every time you want to load a web page. Just use the UIWebView's loadRequest: method to change the URL you want to point the user to.
I hope this reduces you memory consumption.

Comment: Would there be low memory issues when the file size is VERY large? say over 10MB? even with a single instance?

Comment: not sure, it all depends upon the Content of the Page. If text then might not effect, but If Images it might. You should test it though.